# How to expand a FontAwesome icon

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I use the following **Font Awesome** font on my site with SVG's:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/toggle-on?style=solid

How can I widen this Font Awesome font's width but not height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you cannot change the width/height of icon unless you adjust some property of the SVG like `preserveAspectRatio` for example which will not give you a good result

```css
svg {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="none" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="toggle-on" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" ><path fill="currentColor" d="M384 64H192C86 64 0 150 0 256s86 192 192 192h192c106 0 192-86 192-192S490 64 384 64zm0 320c-70.8 0-128-57.3-128-128 0-70.8 57.3-128 128-128 70.8 0 128 57.3 128 128 0 70.8-57.3 128-128 128z" class=""></path></svg>
```

Another idea is to simply recreate this using pure CSS and you can easily scale the width of the icon:

```css
.icon {
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:60px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - 30px) 50%, transparent 20px,orange 21px);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:120px;">
</div>

<div class="icon" style="width:60px;">
</div>
```

You can also control the height by adding CSS variables:

```css
.icon {
  --h:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:calc(2*var(--h));
  width:200px;
  border-radius:calc(2*var(--h));
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at calc(100% - var(--h)) 50%, transparent calc(var(--h) - 10px),orange calc(var(--h) - 9px));
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:120px;--h:40px;">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:100px;--h:20px;">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:60px;">
</div>
```

And you can also have the toggle effect by adjusting `background-position`:

```css
.icon {
  --h:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:calc(2*var(--h));
  width:200px;
  border-radius:calc(2*var(--h));
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle , transparent calc(var(--h) - 10px),orange calc(var(--h) - 9px));
  background-size:calc(200% - 2*var(--h)) 100%;
  transition:1s;
}

.icon:hover {
  background-position:100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:120px;--h:40px;">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:100px;--h:20px;">
</div>
<div class="icon" style="width:60px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if you can just increase the width of the icon without the height, I don't believe that is possible.

Although try:

```
i{
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Play around with the width but leave the height at a fixed value.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. This is the SVG method